# Autoware Auto - Transform from nav_base to base_link is unavailable

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to Autoware and I have recently started working on the setting up the Autoware.

I have successfully installed the Autoware with ADE using the link [here](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation-ade.html).

I am following the [link](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/lgsvl.html) to configure the LGSVL Simulator.

I have created a test simulation using vehicle **Lexus2016RXHybrid (Autoware)** and map **SingleLaneRoad**. As mentioned in the document I have copied the sensor data from [here](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/lgsvl-sensors.json).

I am getting the transformation error when I try to run the below steps,

```
$ ade enter
ade$ source /opt/AutowareAuto/setup.bash
ade$ ros2 run lgsvl_interface lgsvl_interface_exe --ros-args --params-file /opt/AutowareAuto/share/lgsvl_interface/param/lgsvl.param.yaml
```

Error details:

```
[ERROR] [1618066657.298942991] [lgsvl_interface]: Transform from nav_base to base_link is unavailable. Waiting...
Warning: Invalid frame ID "base_link" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist at line 133 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-tf2-0.13.9/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ERROR] [1618066658.298681311] [lgsvl_interface]: Transform from nav_base to base_link is unavailable. Waiting...
```

I would be great help if you could help me to find the fix for this.

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375863/autoware-auto---transform-from-nav_base-to-base_link-is-unavailable./) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2021-04-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [George123](https://answers.ros.org/users/34325/george123/) on 2021-05-23**:
Hello have you resolved the issue? Can you provide more insight what command did you used?

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-05-23**:
You need to run the below command:
`ros2 run robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher lexus_rx_450h.urdf`
Let me know if there are any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transform from `nav_base` to `base_link` is the offset between the center of gravity (`nav_base`) and the center of the rear axle (`base_link`). This can either be published with a `static_transform_publisher` or by providing a URDF file to the `robot_state_publisher`. We provide a URDF file for the Lexus under `src/urdf/lexus_rx_450h_description/urdf/`. Or, if you are using `ade`, you can also find it under `/opt/AutowareAuto/share/lexus_rx_450h_description/urdf/`. See http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-04-11**:
Thanks for the response, I will try the above steps and let you know if any queries.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-04-20**:
This helped me to setup the autoware with LGSVL. Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-18**:
If this fixed the issue, please press the grey check button so others can see it too.

[image: image description]